# How to change user name?

Tags: macos, mac

I am rookie in mac and first time when I got mac I set user name as Admin therefore all that associate with the mac begin with name Admin.

I would like to change this name to Aleksey

I found in System Preferences tab where it could be changed

[image]

But I am not sure that if I change name I will not get errors in consequences , because as far as I understand such way I will change path.

Eventually I am not sure that path will be changed in all apps where it has been taken

If my explanation not clear feel free to ask

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71540/how-to-change-account-name-and-full-name-to-one-consistent-name?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have sufficient space on your drive to duplicate your user account temporarily…

1. Copy your home folder /Users/old-username to /Users/new-username.

   ```
   sudo cp -a /Users/old-username /Users/new-username
   ```
2. Create a new user account in Users & Groups. Enter the new-username as the username when creating the account. You will be prompted with the following:

   > The Users folder already contains a folder with the same name as the home folder for this account.

   Choose Use Existing Folder.
3. Log out of your old-username and log in to your new-username.
4. Once you've verified everything is as it should be, you can delete the old-username account.
5. If permissions are incorrect, continue from step 7 of the next section.

If you *don't* have sufficient space to duplicate…

1. You even more so need a backup before proceeding with this method.
2. Create a new user account or use an existing secondary administrator account. This account must not have either old-username or new-username. Log in to this account. Make sure you are not using Fast User Switching and old-username is correctly logged out.
3. From this account, rename /Users/old-username to /Users/new-username using Finder.
4. In Users & Groups, unlock the preference pane, right-click on old-username and choose Advanced Options…. You'll be presented with the pane you screenshot in your question.
5. Change Account name to new-username and Home directory to /Users/new-username.
6. Quit System Preferences. Do **not** log in to new-username yet.
7. Shut down your Mac and boot into the Recovery HD by holding ⌘R on boot.
8. Open Terminal from the Utilities menu and run `resetpassword`. A new dialog will be shown.
9. Select new-username from the accounts list, then click Reset for Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs.
10. Once complete, restart and boot normally, then log in with new-username.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201548 indicates that the resetpassword command is not necessary (nor should it be since the userID number is not changed). It might be a good idea anyway though.

Comment: @j-beda I've done this procedure a few times and I've had odd permission problems happen with third-party apps, so I just recommend it anyway, also see the other questions on this site where people have changed username and my answer suggesting resetpassword solving the problem.

Comment: @grgaside, probably good advice for the duplication instructions too.